# Using James Server in Eclipse With JavaMail

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-mail, james

Would anyone be able to tell me how I can go about using James server as my server with Java in Eclipse?

I'm trying to test the two classes posted below but i get the following error:
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: Authentication failed.

```
public class JamesConfigTest
{
public static void main(String[] args)
throws Exception
{
// CREATE CLIENT INSTANCES
MailClient redClient = new MailClient("red", "localhost");
MailClient greenClient = new MailClient("green", "localhost");
MailClient blueClient = new MailClient("blue", "localhost");

// CLEAR EVERYBODY'S INBOX
redClient.checkInbox(MailClient.CLEAR_MESSAGES);
greenClient.checkInbox(MailClient.CLEAR_MESSAGES);
blueClient.checkInbox(MailClient.CLEAR_MESSAGES);
Thread.sleep(500); // Let the server catch up

// SEND A COUPLE OF MESSAGES TO BLUE (FROM RED AND GREEN)
redClient.sendMessage(
  "blue@localhost",
  "Testing blue from red",
  "This is a test message");
greenClient.sendMessage(
  "blue@localhost",
  "Testing blue from green",
  "This is a test message");
Thread.sleep(500); // Let the server catch up

// LIST MESSAGES FOR BLUE (EXPECT MESSAGES FROM RED AND GREEN)
blueClient.checkInbox(MailClient.SHOW_AND_CLEAR);
}
}


import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class MailClient
extends Authenticator
{
public static final int SHOW_MESSAGES = 1;
public static final int CLEAR_MESSAGES = 2;
public static final int SHOW_AND_CLEAR =
SHOW_MESSAGES + CLEAR_MESSAGES;

protected String from;
protected Session session;
protected PasswordAuthentication authentication;

public MailClient(String user, String host)
{
this(user, host, false);
}

public MailClient(String user, String host, boolean debug)
{
from = user + '@' + host;
authentication = new PasswordAuthentication(user, user);
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.user", user);
props.put("mail.host", host);
props.put("mail.debug", debug ? "true" : "false");
props.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
session = Session.getInstance(props, this);
}

public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
{
return authentication;
}

public void sendMessage(
String to, String subject, String content)
  throws MessagingException
{
System.out.println("SENDING message from " + from + " to " + to);
System.out.println();
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
msg.setSubject(subject);
msg.setText(content);
Transport.send(msg);
}

public void checkInbox(int mode)
   throws MessagingException, IOException
{
if (mode == 0) return;
boolean show = (mode & SHOW_MESSAGES) > 0;
boolean clear = (mode & CLEAR_MESSAGES) > 0;
String action =
  (show ? "Show" : "") +
  (show && clear ? " and " : "") +
  (clear ? "Clear" : "");
System.out.println(action + " INBOX for " + from);
Store store = session.getStore();
store.connect();
Folder root = store.getDefaultFolder();
Folder inbox = root.getFolder("inbox");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
Message[] msgs = inbox.getMessages();
if (msgs.length == 0 && show)
{
  System.out.println("No messages in inbox");
}
for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++)
{
  MimeMessage msg = (MimeMessage)msgs[i];
  if (show)
  {
    System.out.println("    From: " + msg.getFrom()[0]);
    System.out.println(" Subject: " + msg.getSubject());
    System.out.println(" Content: " + msg.getContent());
  }
  if (clear)
  {
    msg.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
  }
  }
  inbox.close(true);
  store.close();
  System.out.println();
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException problem. Basically I fixed it by deleting the user blue with the command "deluser blue" and then adding the user again using the command "adduser blue blue". After that it worked.